# How to convert byte[] to PDF in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, pdf-generation, arrays

I am trying to create a PDF file out of a byte array. Before writing the bytes to the file I print them as a string and the contents get printed correctly but when I open the automatically downloaded PDF file, it won't open as the file is somehow damaged.

```
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    long logFileId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter(REQUEST_PARAM_DOCUMENT_ID));
    MappingInfo mapping = documentService.getMapping(logFileId);
    byte[] file = mapping.getImportLogs();

    System.out.println(new String(file));

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(file.length);

    // response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=ImportLog.pdf");
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(file);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
  }
```

Can someone please point out the mistake I am making here? I am also trying not to use any third party APIs.

Thanks

Comment: You need a 3rd party library (e.g. `iText` from Apache) in order to write PDF.  You can't simply write bytes to a file, unless those bytes come from another PDF.

Comment: The `response.reset();` is clearing all your headers. I would remove that line.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis removed but still the same issue.

Comment: *convert byte[] to PDF* - What does your `byte[]` contain?If it does not yet contain a PDF, how do you want to style your PDF?

Comment: @mkl it contains a String(of characters), which I managed to Sysout successfully.

Comment: *it contains a String(of characters)* - then you indeed need a PDF library like @TimBiegeleisen already mentioned (he is wrong, though, assuming iText to be from Apache...).

Comment: Which is the preferred library for this? Is there anything from Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example from JavaPoint.
http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-write-data-into-PDF-using-servlet

Comment: Your example does not show how to convert a byte [] to a PDF

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that we **must** use a third party API for this. I am able to achieve this using iText API. Might help someone else.

```
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    long logFileId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter(REQUEST_PARAM_DOCUMENT_ID));
    MappingInfo mapping = documentService.getMapping(logFileId);
    byte[] file = mapping.getImportLogs();

    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    try {
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outStream);
      document.open();
      document.add(new Paragraph(new String(file)));
      document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
      document.add(new Paragraph("a paragraph"));
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();

    response.setContentLength(file.length);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=ImportLog.pdf");
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    outStream.write(file);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
  }
```